# Recursively rename the files and folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109927/rename-folders-files-in-a-windows-system-recursively) post and I can't meet my requirements.

My Folder structure is:

```
_TEMPLATE_
|_ _TEMPLATE_SUBFOLDER1
|   |_ _TEMPLATE_SUB_SUBFOLDER1
|   |   |_ _TEMPLATE_FILE11.txt
|   |   |_ _TEMPLATE_FILE12.xml
|   |_ _TEMPLATE_SUB_SUBFOLDER2
|   |   |_ _TEMPLATE_FILE21.txt
|   |   |_ _TEMPLATE_FILE22.xml
|   |_ TEMPLATE_SUB_SUBFOLDER3
|_ _TEMPLATE_SUBFOLDER2
    |_TEMPLATE_FILE3.xml
```

I want to replace the `_TEMPLATE_` to desired name 
for ex. `Stores` so result will be

```
Stores
|_ StoresSUBFOLDER1
|   |_ StoresSUB_SUBFOLDER1
|   |   |_ StoresFILE11.txt
|   |   |_ StoresFILE12.xml
|   |_ StoresSUB_SUBFOLDER2
|   |   |_ StoresFILE21.txt
|   |   |_ StoresFILE22.xml
|   |_ StoresSUB_SUBFOLDER3
|_ StoresSUBFOLDER2
    |StoresFILE3.xml
```

I searched web there is option to traverse only files. and none of them go **recursive rename** 
Thank you.

Comment: possibe duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717171/recursive-renaming-file-names-folder-names-with-a-batch-file

Comment: @Dirk thanks.. :) the post help me on renaming files but it didn't renaming folders.. anyway half of the work done.. how to recursively rename subfolders?

Comment: To rename folders you'll have to use an additional loop, but with `for /r /d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested, but I think this will work

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad /s _TEMPLATE_*') do (
  set "fname=%%~nxF"
  set "fpath=%%~dpF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!fpath:_TEMPLATE_=Stores!!fname!" "!fname:_TEMPLATE_=Stores!"
  endlocal
)
```

It is perhaps a bit tricky because the loop is modifying the folder names of the hierarchy that it is enumerating. The parent folder of each folder will already have been renamed by the time it gets there.

It will not give the correct results if your root path that is not getting renamed also has `_TEMPLATE_` in the name.

I toggle delayed expansion within the loop to protect against corruption of `!` in path names during expansion of the FOR variable. If you know that no folder names contain `!` then you can  use `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` at the top and remove the SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL from the loop.